# How to grab text inside a script tag with scrapy?

Tags: html, scrapy

I need to grab as text the contents of a script tag with a very specific attribute with the scrapy library. Essentialy the BeautifulSoup equivalent of this:

```
js_content = soup.find("script",type="application/ld+json").get_text()
```

I tried this, but the result is not quite what I need.

`response.css('script').attrib['type']`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

CSS:

```py
response.css('script[type="application/ld+json"]::text').get()
```

xpath:

```py
response.xpath('//script[@type="application/ld+json"]/text()').get()
```

Basically we're finding a `script` tag that has an attribute `type` with a value of `application/ld+json` and grabbing the text.